# Speed and Velocity in German

Tags: english-to-german, difference, single-word-request, vocabulary

As I understand it there are two different words for "how fast an object is moving" in English:

- *velocity*, tells you how the x,y,z (in 3 dimensions) coordinates of an object change over time. It's a vector quantity, hence has direction and magnitude. For example

  [image]
- *speed*, tells you how fast the object covers distance. It's a scalar quantity with no direction. For example

  [image]

Do you distinguish between the vector / scalar quantity in German too? I only know the word "Geschwindigkeit" and I think it's used in both cases. Is there another word that only describes either "speed" or "velocity"?

Comment: I didn’t know English made this distinction. I always thought that *velocity* is just a more fancy and scientific way of saying *speed* …

Comment: @Jan It is...apparently. Its always been my tripping point whenever I'm solving kinematics questions.

Comment: IMHO, outside physics this distinction is normally not made in *both* English and German. And German doesn't have a word to make the distinction.

Comment: @Jan In a way, that's right - speed is how far you walk. Velocyty is much more fancy because it also has a direction: You can walk around a corner with constant speed, but not with constant velocity.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, we do not make such a clear distinction in German. The German counterpart for Wikipedias entry on velocity is titled [*Geschwindigkeit*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geschwindigkeit), and it explains:

> Oft wird mit dem Wort Geschwindigkeit nur ihr Betrag gemeint..., der anschaulich gesprochen das momentane „Tempo“ der Bewegung wiedergibt.

From there you see that we also use *Geschwindigkeit* when we mean *speed*, and it also offers another option *Tempo* when you really need a second word.

Comment: A friend of mine who is a physics teacher tells me that in class, she makes the distinction between Geschwindigkeit as a vector and Tempo as a scalar. But I agree most people would not make that distinction. Also, Tempo is a word that I'd expect in spoken rather than written language.

Answer (score 33):

You have to append *vektor* in German when you have to make clear a vector is meant. **Geschwindigkeitsvektor**

(note the linking *s* between the two word parts and also note *vektor* is spoken with an *o* as in the English word *core*)

This applies to any other physical variables as well.

Comment: What do you mean by "the linking s between the two word parts (...) is spoken with an *o* (...)"? How can an *s* be spoken with an *o*?

Comment: The 's' between Geschwindigkeit and Vektor is called Fugen-s

Comment: @Mapper He means that the 'o' in the word "Vektor" is spoken like the o in the English word "core". The s doesn't have anything to do with the pronunciation.

Answer (score 5):

Another word for *speed* is also *Schnelligkeit*, as you can see from [these](http://www.sotere.uni-osnabrueck.de/Lehre/skript/biophys-master.pdf) lecture notes (p. 52) from a German university.

But to be honest, only distinguishing *velocity* vs. *speed*  but not scalar vs. vectorial *acceleration* is a little strange.